# What tool should I use to create my buildmachine?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, cross-compiling, build-server

I am working on my free time on a multiplatform/multi-architecture library written in `C++`.

Before every release, I have to boot up several computers (One on Windows, one on Linux, another one on Mac OS, ...) just to make sure the code compiles and runs fine on every platform.

So I decided to create my own buildmachine but I really don't know what tools exist to do this. I'd like my buildmachine to run on Linux but any other solution will be accepted.

Ideally, I would just have to click on a "Build all" button, and it would compile my library for the different platforms/architectures, generate archives from the result and/or report potential errors.

My project "constraints" are:

- It is written in `C++`
- It compiles on Windows using SConstruct/MinGW and Visual Studio 2010
- It compile on Linux and Mac OS using SConstruct/g++
- The sources are stored into Subversion (svn)

Do you know any tool/set of tools that could help me achieving my goal ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: A question rather than any kind of insight? If VS on Windows, why SConstruct on Mac? I just maintain parallel VS & XCode projects - on top of the same sources of course. I toyed with the idea of using Code::Blocks so I could build one project on Win, Mac and Linux, but its just so ... unfinished.

Comment: @Chis Becke: I don't know XCode well, so I can't really answer. But my SConstruct file works on all systems so I didn't wanted to add support for another build-system. The compatibilty with Visual Studio 2010 was a special request from a friend of mine which uses it in his company. If it was up to me, I would only use SConstruct, as it fills all my needs.

Comment: One of these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software#Continuous_Integration_Tools ??? I looked into buildbot a while a go, running different targets inside a VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would setup 3 VMs ([VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is free), one for each platform.

Install [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) (or Hudson) on Linux and agents on the other VMs and then it's just a matter of configuring the build system.

At the very basic level you should have 2 tasks: one to checkout the sources from Subversion and another to invoke `scons`.

I'm not too familiar with Hudson but TeamCity is certainly capable of generating reports of a build, display progress etc.

Comment: +1 I use TeamCity for building in a Windows environment. I have not had experience of using it on Linux, but build agents on Linux are supported. TeamCity is a nice piece of kit - highly recommended.

Comment: +1 for Virtual Box and an toolset to script it. Can you really get OS X to boot in a VM on non Mac hardware though? Without resorting to technically illegal workarounds?

Comment: @Chris: I'm not very familiar with OSX to be quite honest. But either way, without knowing more on his actual setup (are these separate machines? is he triple booting into the different operating systems?) he just needs to install the agent on his Mac.